Create 301 redirect for all 404 pages to the homepage (404 with any URL combination)
I'm trying creating a redirect for all the 404 pages straight to my homepage. I have tried creating it through .htaccess but seems like it does not worked. .htaccess may ask for the old url & a new url
Redirect 301 old-url-key new-url-key

This is not suitable in my case. Tried generic rule but that also don't worked. Either it is redirecting all the pages to the homepage. OR specified url to the homepage. I want to permanent redirect only 404 pages that could occur with any url_key combination and 301 redirected to homepage.
Is there a way to achieve it via .htaccess OR module?
I have also tried it with a module but it creates a 302 redirect even I have made it to 301 programmatically.  Below is the code snippet for module
<?php

namespace Your\Module\Controller;

use Magento\Framework\App\Router\NoRouteHandlerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface;
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;

class NoRouteHandler implements NoRouteHandlerInterface
{
    protected $response;
    protected $url;

    public function __construct(
        ResponseInterface $response,
        UrlInterface $url
    ) {
        $this->response = $response;
        $this->url = $url;
    }

    public function process(RequestInterface $request)
    {
        $homeUrl = $this->url->getUrl('');
        $this->response->setStatusHeader(301, '1.1', 'Moved Permanently');
        $this->response->setRedirect($homeUrl, 301);

        return false;
    }
}

<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <type name="Magento\Framework\App\Router\NoRouteHandlerList">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="handlerClassesList" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="redirect404" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">Your\Module\Controller\NoRouteHandler</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">20</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>



PHP isn't the best practice for this kind of action. You don't need to go to the PHP level to achieve this web server level like nginx should do the trick.
server {

    ...

    error_page 404 = /;

    ...
}

Overall redirecting 404 to the front page is not a good practice because it affects your SEO score if you have broken links and that is causing the problem in the first place.
Keep this in mind. I would rather focus on fixing the 404 errors if there isn't any purpose for those.
https://wpslimseo.com/404-redirect-to-homepage/#the-impact-of-404-errors-on-seo
"404 errors can have a negative impact on your website's search engine optimization (SEO). When search engines crawl your website, they follow links from one page to another, and if they encounter a 404 error, they may assume that your website is not well-maintained or that you have removed important content. As a result, the website's search engine rankings may suffer, making it harder for potential customers to find the site."
